# How to get the records according to the where clauses in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been facing a small confusion from which I am not able to get rid.
I have a table "**user_questions**" with the attributes **id**, **question_sequence_number**, **title**. From that table I want to take the records according to the priority given like first I have given '**question_sequence_number**' and then '**id**'. So what I want is that the records should be displayed **first** with the **sequence numbers** I have given and the records should be displayed **next** with **Ids** I have given. 
For that I have written a **mySql** query something like follows:

```
SELECT "user_questions".* FROM "user_questions" WHERE (question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19) OR id IN (198,199,200,201,202))
```

But the records are coming first with **ids** I have given and the remaining records with **question sequence number**.

Can anybody please help me out in this to achieve ?

Thanks.

Comment: it is good if you can give sample data and desire output, but talking about your query, the query your wrote only filter records, doesn't define sequency, try using ORDER BY Clause to get them in sequence.

Comment: I can give ORDER BY question_sequence_number desc, records will come with question_sequence_number but with reverse like (19,16,13,11).

Comment: I want to get the results in the way exactly what I mentioned in the question_sequence_number sequence in the query.

Comment: **Don't quote/backtick your table & column names.**  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the order of records you need you have to use `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise the order is not guaranteed.

That being said you can try something like this

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM user_questions
 WHERE question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19) 
    OR id IN (198,199,200,201,202)
 ORDER BY (question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19)) DESC,
          CASE WHEN question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19) 
               THEN question_sequence_number
               ELSE id
          END
```

Output:

```
|  ID | QUESTION_SEQUENCE_NUMBER |
|-----|--------------------------|
|   2 |                       11 |
|   4 |                       13 |
|   3 |                       16 |
|   1 |                       19 |
| 198 |                        5 |
| 199 |                        4 |
| 200 |                        3 |
| 201 |                        2 |
| 202 |                        1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89331/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE _Str VARCHAR(500);
SET _Str=CONCAT("SELECT user_questions.* FROM user_questions WHERE (question_sequence_number IN ("11,13,16,19") OR id IN ("198,199,200,201,202")")
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```